# Definition an action of a group on itself and its orbits (GAP)

Tags: group-theory, math-software, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group. $x \sim y$ iff there exists $g \in G$ such that $$ \langle x \rangle = g^{-1} \langle y ‎\rangle g $$ where $\langle x \rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $x$. Then $G$ acts on itself. What is the orbits of this action? For example let $G = D_{14}$ then the action is:

```
gap> ac:=function(x,t) return Group((x))^t; end;;
```

but, how to define the command "Orbits" for it? I set the following commands but it is not correct.

```
gap> o:=Orbits(G,G,ac);
gap> o:=Orbits(G,Elements(G),ac);
```

Comment: Inja ro bebinid [*](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/398111/8581). Maybe it helps you.

Comment: If you're trying to write `ac` as `actfun` from [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap41.html#X81B8F9CD868CD953) then there is a type mismatch: it takes an element `x` of the action domain, and `t` from the acting group, and it must return **an element of the action domain** again.

Comment: Dear Alexander Konovalov, Thank you very much for the useful comments. In the following the GAP program for finding this action is given, 


act:=function(x,t) return x^t; end;;
l:=List(ConjugacyClasses(g),Representative);;
dd:=[];;
for j in [1..Size(l)] do c:=Group(l[j]);Add(dd,c);od;;
ss:=Set(dd);;
oo:=Orbits(g,ss,act);  Best regards

Comment: Good! Using `OnPoints` which is a standard action defined [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap41.html), all could be done much simpler: `D:=DihedralGroup(14);Orbits(D,D,OnPoints);`. I could post it a a proper answer later, if this answers your question.

Comment: This action gives different orbites as my action.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I haven't run your code and did not spot that it acts on subgroups. Anyhow, `OnPoints` also works here - just try `oo:=Orbits(g,ss,OnPoints);`. This works because `OnPoints` works if `g^t` is defined, and this is the case when `g` is a group on which `t` acts by conjugation.

Answer (score 2):

The initial problem with the acting function is the type mismatch: in

```
gap> ac:=function(x,t) return Group((x))^t; end;;
```

the 1st argument is a group element, and the output is a subgroup. As GAP manual explains [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap41.html#X81B8F9CD868CD953), the acting function must take an element x of the action domain, and t from the acting group, and return an element of the action domain again.

Your second attempt works, indeed - just pasting the code from your comment to display it nicely:

```
g:=DihedralGroup(14);
act:=function(x,t) return x^t; end;; 
l:=List(ConjugacyClasses(g),Representative);; 
dd:=[];; 
for j in [1..Size(l)] do 
  c:=Group(l[j]);
  Add(dd,c);
od;; 
ss:=Set(dd);; 
oo:=Orbits(g,ss,act);
```

because now `act` conforms to the specification. The last line can be replaced by

```
oo:=Orbits(g,ss,OnPoints);
```

since your action is just another case of `OnPoints`, since `g^t` is defined when `g` is a group on which `t` acts by conjugation.

A minor improvement might be to use `AddSet` in the loop instead of `Set` after the loop, to avoid forming a large list `c`. Moreover, if you're interested in conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups, then (dependently on the group) it may be easier to use `ConjugacyClassesSubgroups`, and then select classes that contain cyclic subgroups.

Comment: $+1{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$